# How to (correctly) use the cocoa Security Framework

Tags: swift, security, cocoa

I am trying to use the Security framework provided by Apple to authorize users of my app. I have created three rights using the following rule. Right 1 has a timeout of 0, the others of 600.

```
[
    kAuthorizationRightRule: kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsSessionUser,
    "key": "my.right.name",
    "shared": false,
    "timeout": 0 // Either 0 or 600
]
```

The first time I obtain right 1 via SFAuthorization.obtain, a prompt is shown. When I then try to obtain it again, I expected to be prompted for my password again, but instead it is immediately granted. Even when I try to obtain right 2 or 3, no prompt is shown anymore after granting right 1.

I tried to find information on this framework via Google and SO, as the Apple docs are not really helpful, but without success.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

My code (simplified):

```
class AuthorizationManager {

    private static let authorization = SFAuthorization.authorization() as! SFAuthorization

    static func setup() {
        var currentRight: CFDictionary?
        var status: OSStatus

        for right in Right.all {
            status = AuthorizationRightGet(right.name, &currentRight)

            if status == errAuthorizationDenied {
                status = AuthorizationRightSet(self.authorization.authorizationRef(), right.name, right.rule, right.description, nil, nil)
            }
            if status != errAuthorizationSuccess {
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }

    static func request(rights: [Right]) -> Bool {
        var authItems = rights.map { $0.authItem }
        var authRights = AuthorizationRights(count: UInt32(authItems.count), items: &authItems)

        do {
            try self.authorization.obtain(withRights: &authRights, flags: [.interactionAllowed, .extendRights], environment: nil, authorizedRights: nil)
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

And the Right enum:

```
enum Right {
        case right1
        case right2
        case right3

        static let all: [Right] = [.right1, .right2, .right3]

        private var data: (name: String, timeout: Int) {
            switch self {
            case .right1:
                return ("right.name.one", 0)
            case .right2:
                return ("right.name.two", 600)
            case .right3:
                return ("right.name.three", 600)
            }
        }

        fileprivate var name: UnsafePointer<Int8> {
            return (self.data.name as NSString).utf8String!
        }

        fileprivate var description: CFString {
            let description: String
            switch self {
            case .right1:
                description = "First right description"
            case .right2:
                description = "Second right description"
            case .right3:
                description = "Third right description"
            }
            return description as CFString
        }

        fileprivate var rule: CFDictionary {
            return [
                kAuthorizationRightRule: kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsSessionUser,
                "key": self.data.name,
                "shared": false,
                "timeout": self.data.timeout
            ] as CFDictionary
        }

        fileprivate var authItem: AuthorizationItem {
            return AuthorizationItem(name: self.name, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think this is how the authorisation is supposed to work. Otherwise you can consider some other frameworks as suggested on the API documentation...

Comment: @DominikBucher Well, based on what the documentation states, I would think that at least a timeout of 0 would result in a prompt every time.
_For maximum security where the user must authenticate or consent every time, set the timeout to 0._

Comment: I have never worked with this API, but do you create everytime new securitySession? It seems like it's crucial to create a new one before anything else... Could you provide somehow the algorithm of your implementation?

Comment: @DominikBucher I have updated the question with my implementation

Comment: @DominikBucher What did you mean with creating a new security session? I could not find that in the docs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that setting the `kAuthorizationRightRule` attribute caused the other attributes to be ignored. After some more research, I found that using the following dictionary as rule gave the same results as `kAuthorizationRuleAuthenticateAsSessionUser`, but with a timeout set:

```
[
  "key": "my.right.name",
  "allow-root": false,
  "authenticate-user": true,
  "class": "user",
  "session-owner": true,
  "shared": false,
  "timeout": 0
]
```

Also, to prevent the other rights from not showing a prompt, multiple SFAuthorization objects should be used.